# python - jogo da cobrinha/projeto faculdade

Tags: python, jogos

Preciso criar um programa que simule uma espécie de "jogo da cobrinha" usando apenas variáveis booleanas, funções básicas e repetidores. Até o momento meu programa se encontra assim:

```
print()
print('=================================================')
print('         Bem-vindo ao Jogo da Cobrinha!          ')
print('=================================================')
print()

nlinhas = int(input('Número de linhas do tabuleiro : '))
ncols   = int(input('Número de colunas do tabuleiro: '))
x0      = int(input('Posição x inicial da cobrinha : '))
y0      = int(input('posição y inicial da cobrinha : '))
t       = int(input('Tamanho da cobrinha           : '))

# Verifica se corpo da cobrinha cabe na linha do tabuleiro,
# considerando a posição inicial escolhida para a cabeça
if x0 - (t - 1) < 0:
    # Não cabe
    print()
    print("A COBRINHA NÃO PODE FICAR NA POSIÇÃO INICIAL INDICADA")

else:

    ''' Inicia a variável d indicando nela que t-1 partes do corpo
        da cobrinha estão inicialmente alinhadas à esquerda da cabeça.
        Exemplos:
           se t = 4, então devemos fazer d = 222
           se t = 7, então devemos fazer d = 222222
    '''
    d = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= t-1:
        d = d * 10 + 2
        i = i + 1

    # Laço que controla a interação com o jogador
    direcao = 1
    while direcao != 5:
        # mostra tabuleiro com a posição atual da cobrinha
        imprime_tabuleiro(nlinhas, ncols, x0, y0, d)

        # lê o número do próximo movimento que será executado no jogo
        print("1 - esquerda | 2 - direita | 3 - cima | 4 - baixo | 5 - sair do jogo")
        direcao = int(input("Digite o número do seu próximo movimento: "))

        if direcao != 5:
            # atualiza a posição atual da cobrinha
            x0, y0, d = move(nlinhas, ncols, x0, y0, d, direcao)

print()        
print("Tchau!")

# ======================================================================

def num_digitos(n):
    """ (int) -> int

    Devolve o número de dígitos de um número.

    ENTRADA
    - n: número a ser verificado 

    """
    # Escreva sua função a seguir e corrija o valor devolvido no return

    n = int(input('qual é o numero: ')) 
    num_digitos = 0
    i = 0
    while n != 0:
        i = n % 10
        n = n // 10 
        num_digitos = num_digitos + 1
        i = i + 1

    print("Número de digitos é", num_digitos)

    return num_digitos

# ======================================================================
def pos_ocupada(nlinhas, ncols, x, y, x0, y0, d):
    """(int, int, int, int, int, int, int) -> bool

    Devolve True se alguma parte da cobra ocupa a posição (x,y) e
    False no caso contrário.

    ENTRADAS
    - nlinhas, ncols: número de linhas e colunas do tabuleiro
    - x, y: posição a ser testada
    - x0, y0: posição da cabeça da cobra
    - d: sequência de deslocamentos que levam a posição da cauda da cobra
         até a cabeça; o dígito menos significativo é a direção na cabeça

    """

    # Escreva sua função a seguir e corrija o valor devolvido no return
    Achei = False

    while (d != 0):
        resto = d % 10
        d = d // 10

        if resto == 1:
            x0 = x0 + 1

        if resto == 2:
            x0 = x0 - 1

        if resto == 3:
            y0 = y0 - 1

        if resto == 4:
            y0 = y0 + 1

        if x == x0 and y == y0:
            achei = True


    return True


# ======================================================================
def imprime_tabuleiro(nlinhas, ncols, x0, y0, d):
    """(int, int, int, int, int, int)

    Imprime o tabuleiro com a cobra.

    ENTRADAS
    - nlinhas, ncols: número de linhas e colunas do tabuleiro
    - x0, y0: posição da cabeça da cobra
    - d: sequência de deslocamentos que levam a posição da cauda da cobra
         até a cabeça; o dígito menos significativo é a direção na cabeça

    """


     # Escreva sua função a seguir
    print("Vixe! Ainda não fiz a função imprime_tabuleiro()!")



# ======================================================================
def move(nlinhas, ncols, x0, y0, d, direcao):
    """(int, int, int, int, int, int) -> int, int, int

    Move a cobra na direção dada.    
    A função devolve os novos valores de x0, y0 e d (nessa ordem).
    Se o movimento é impossível (pois a cobra vai colidir consigo mesma ou
    com a parede), então a função devolve os antigos valores e imprime a
    mensagem apropriada: "COLISÃO COM SI MESMA" ou "COLISÃO COM A PAREDE"

    ENTRADAS
    - nlinhas, ncols: número de linhas e colunas do tabuleiro
    - x0, y0: posição da cabeça da cobra
    - d: sequência de deslocamentos que levam a posição da cauda da cobra
         até a cabeça; o dígito menos significativo é a direção na cabeça
    - direcao: direção na qual a cabeça deve ser movida

    """

    # Escreva sua função a seguir e corrija o valor devolvido no return
    print("Vixe! Ainda não fiz a função move()!")

    return x0, y0, d

# ======================================================================
main()
```

já consegui fazer as funções `num_digitos` e `pos_ocupada`, porém não sei como começar a função que imprime o tabuleiro do jogo  e nem a que move a cobra.

Answer (score 5):

## Criando um jogo da cobrinha no terminal, do zero

Revendo sua pergunta - eu realmente não respondi  que você precisa - é um exercício de faculdade de reconstrução dos passos da cobrinha a partir da direção  - e é s[o teórico, com m 0 preocupação se o jogo seria real ou não.

Mais tarde, talvez,e u ponha uma resposta menor com as dicas que você precisa para o exercício - não quer dizer que você não deva deixar os exercícios que não servem pra nada prático na geladeira um pouco e estudar este:

## Tutorial de Jogo da Cobrinha completo em modo texto

Bom - você tem um outro problema aí - 
se o jogo precisa ser no modo texto, não há uma forma padronizada, entre sistemas operacionais como Linux e OS X  e o Windows sobre como desenhar uma tela interativa no terminal - ou ler o teclado em tempo real (sem o jogador ter que apertar `<enter>` após cada movimento).

Ou seja - esse é um jogo que já foi simples num momento passado em que as interfaces de texto ofereciam uma opção fixa de controle. Agora - justamente essas funções de "veja que caractere está na posição tal" e "imprima um caractere na posição tal" é que deixavam criar jogos como esse de forma simples. Eu vou sugerir uma biblioteca para fazer o tal joguinho no modo texto - e ai com alguns exemplos, você vai ver que o jogo é ao mesmo tempo mais simples do que o que você está fazendo, e mais divertido em termos de programação.

Hoje em dia, nos ambientes Linux e OS X, com Python, você pode usar a biblioteca "curses"  que vem com o Python. Já no Windows, por padrão, não funciona "curses" e você terá que usar a biblioteca `msvcrt` . Você poderia determinar que só vai precisar de 3 coisas: (1) ler uma das teclas-seta em tempo "real" - (isso é, sem esperar o enter), (2) poder limpar  a tela e (3) poder imprimir um caractere numa posição arbitrária (linha e coluna) da tela.  Hmmm, vendo a documentação -- o "msvcrt" nao permite (3) - você está de volta no mato sem cachorro.

Ah - (santo Google) - existe uma forma de instalar o "curses" para Windows - está nesta resposta aceita do stackoverflow em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417379/what-is-needed-for-curses-in-python-3-4-on-windows7

Isso dito, o Curses é um pouco chato - o seu programa ou imprime e usa input, como você faz, ou faz tudo pelo curses - a documentação dele esta aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html  - por isso nem vou tentar colocar suporte a esse monte de perguntas e respostas pra começar o jogo que você fez. (e convenhamos - é bem legal agora que você já sabe sobre o `input` e colocar seu valor numa variável - mas quem vai querer ficar respondendo um monte de perguntas só pra começar o joguinho da cobrinha?  :-)  )

Eu estou consultando o tutorial oficial de curses do site do Python em https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#curses-howto e adaptando para a sua questão.

Vamos por partes - primeiro, uma vamos colocar um caractere no terminal texto que possa ser movido com as teclas seta, usando a biblioteca "curses". Unicode tem um monte de caracteres legais, mas já que é pra ser "raiz", vamos usar um "*".

```
import curses
import locale
import time
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def main(screen):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    screen.nodelay(True)

    y, x = 20, 20
    direction = (0, 1)
    while True:
        key = screen.getch()
        if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            x -= 1
        elif key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            x += 1
        elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            y += 1
        elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
            y -= 1
        elif key in (0x1b, ord("q")): # <ESC>
            break
        screen.addstr(y, x, b"*")
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)


curses.wrapper(main)
```

Você percebe que o curses tem uma porção de burocracias - temos que chamar o `setlocale` para poder imprimir carácteres unicode (num terminal com unicode, claro), temos que chamar o curs_set, nodelay para suprimir o cursor do modo texto e para ele não ficar esperando o `<enter>`, como um `input` comum.  Além disso, a chamada `wrapper` que chama a função `main` já inicializa a tela, e configura umas 4 ou 5 coisas.

Com essas chamadas fora do caminho, podemos começar a pensar no programa - 
eu ponho o "*" inicialmente na posição "20, 20" (pra que ficar perguntando pro usuário isso? - o jogo pode ter algumas posições de início pré-configuradas, ou pode simplesmente sortear uma posição, mas não vai mudar o jogo ficar perguntando a posição inicial da cobrinha para o usuário -  a não ser pra pior).

No corpo desse "while True" eu estabeleço oq eu chamamos de "laço principal" do jogo - é o techo de código que roda todo o frame de jogo - e que vai atualizar a posição dos elementos, ler o teclado, etc -- por mais sofisticado que seja um jogo - pode ser o GTA VIII - , ele vai ter que ter um "laço principal" - em alguns frameworks de programação de jogos, o laço pode ser embutido no framework, e você só configura algumas funções suas que serão chamadas quando acontecerem eventos - mas o laço está lá.

Dentro do laço, a primeira coisa é chamar `screen.getch()` -  é um método do curses (na verdade no objeto "screen" que o wrapper passa para a nossa função) que lê o código numérico de uma única tecla. COmo setamos o `nodelay` acima, essa chamada retorna instantaneamente - se nenhuma tecla estiver pressionada, ela vai ter um valor especial.

Em seguida, várias linhas de programação Python pura: 5 `if`s  comparando o código pressionado com os das teclas seta - como esses valores, não são padronizados em ASCII ou outro encoding - ao contrário da tecla "q" ou mesmo do "ESC", temos que comparar com constantes pré-definidas no próprio módulo curses.  (Outros frameworks para jogos que permitem leitura de teclado também tem que usar esse recurso para ter o código das setas, teclas de função (F1, F2, ...), "prtscr", etc...)

Mas - então, não tem segredo -se o usuário pressionou "seta pra direita", somamos 1 na coordenada x,e assim por diante.

Em seguida, a chamada à função `addstr(linha, coluna, caractere)` coloca o caractere na posição definida. Pronto - tudo o que precisávamos! So que não - lendo a doc, vemos que ele só desenha mesmo, quando chamamos o método `refresh` - e por fim, uma pausa programada de 1/10 de segundo - para que o asterisco não se mova o mais rápido possível. A duração dessa pausa é que você vai controlar depois, de acordo com o nivel de dificuldade, para determinar a velocidade da cobrinha.

Uma última coisa sobre a "burocracia" de se usar curses: tudo o que você manda pra tela, e pega de volta é em "bytes" - em Python 3, trabalhamos direto com "texto" (as strings de Python 3 são o antigo objeto "unicode" do Python 2) - o que significa que o curses não sabe nada de carácteres acentuados, ou emojis - você tem que passar tudo mastigado pra ele - strings normais de Python tem que ser transformadas em Bytes com seu método "encode" - ou, no caso, como estamos só colocando carácteres simples, podemos escrever os bytes direto colocando um `b"` para abrir a string no código do programa.

ótimo  - teste até aqui - e tenha em mente que quando criaram as primeiras variantes da cobrinha, na década de 70, era *esse* ambiente de terminal que as pessoas tinham.

Agora, pra começar a transformar isso no jogo da cobrinha: (1) ela não pode ficar parada, tem que ter sempre uma direção. Se você usar um único numero para a direção como no seu código, toda vez que for usar a direção vai ter que usar uma sequência de "if"s pra atualizar qualquer coisa. `direcao = 3`: a coordenada y deve ser atualizada? Para cima ou para baixo?

Como teremos que estar atualizando sempre as coordenadas x e y, a direção pode ser uma sequência de dois números, já com os valores para atualizar cada variável.

```
import curses
import locale
import time
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def main(screen):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    screen.nodelay(True)
    y, x = 20, 20
    direction = (1, 0)
    while True:
        key = screen.getch()
        if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            direction = (-1, 0)
        elif key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            direction = (1, 0)
        elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            direction = (0, 1)
        elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
            direction = (0, -1)
        elif key in (0x1b, ord("q")): # <ESC>
            break
        x += direction[0]
        y += direction[1]
        screen.addstr(y, x, b"*")
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Agora, nem preciso ficar explicando mais coisas - perceba que o jogo da cobrinha começa a aparecer naturalmente - e é só uma questão de programação agora. E, surpresa: você não "redesenha a tela toda" nesse tipo de jogo - simplesmente, acrescenta um caractere na nova posição da cabeça da cobrinha, deixando os que já estavam lá - era assim que o jogo ficava rápido nos computadores antigos onde foram criados. (Um jogo moderno redesenha a cena toda, todos os frames, recalculando por vezes dezenas de milhares de polígonos, texturizando e iluminando tudo -se for um jogo 3D)

O que precisamos para o jogo estar completo: fazer com que a cobrinha se "apague" depois que tiver andado o seu tamanho -  e fazer com que ela detecte uma colisão. Para essa segunda parte, ainda podemos usar uma função do `curses` para "ver" o caractere numa dada posição - isso existe - e é o que permitia os joguinhos de cobrinha de antigamente serem mais simples do que hoje. Por que o correto hoje seria em vez de "olhar" para a tela, verificar usando as estruturas de dados que temos, se a cobrinha bateu com algo - seja um a parte dela mesma, uma parede, uma "maçã" (que faz ela aumentar de tamanho e o jogo progredir), etc... Principalmente por que se o jogo for no modo gráfico, ou mesmo em 3D, não é possível "reconhecer" o que está numa posição para onde a cobrinha se move. (nesse caso com o curses, poderíamos ver o caractere e usar um "if" para saber se é um "@" representando uma maçã, ou um "#" representando uma parede, por exemplo). Essa resposta já virou um capítulo de livro, mas não precisa ser o livro inteiro - vou manter o caso simples em que "olhamos" a tela com o método `screen.instr(linha, coluna)`:

import curses
import locale
import time
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()

def main(screen):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    screen.nodelay(True)
    y, x = 20, 20
    direction = (1, 0)
    while True:
        key = screen.getch()
        if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            direction = (-1, 0)
        elif key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            direction = (1, 0)
        elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            direction = (0, 1)
        elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
            direction = (0, -1)
        elif key in (0x1b, ord("q")): # 
            break
        x += direction[0]
        y += direction[1]
        if screen.instr(y, x, 1) != b" ":
            screen.addstr(10, 15, "Você morreu!".encode(encoding))
            screen.refresh()
            time.sleep(3)
            break
        screen.addstr(y, x, b"*")
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)

curses.wrapper(main)

E por fim, criamos um comprimento inicial desejado para a cobrinha, guardamos todas as coordenadas (x, y) pelas quais ela passou - e ao atingir esse comprimento, apagamos o último "*" naquela posição. Graças as listas de Python, é trivial fazer isso. (mas você pode aprender mais e fazer de forma mais elegante usando o `collections.deque`). Isso são literalmente mais 6 linhas de código - e o jogo estaria "completo", exceto que sem graça nenhuma. Aproveito para incluir a "maçã" que aumenta o comprimento da cobrinha em 5 traços de cada vez. Não tem segredo também - usamos o módulo "random" para sortear a maçã. COlocamos pontuação e uma verificação dos limites da tela (o curses expõe o tamanho do terminal em curses.COLS e curses.LINES) - acho que só isso:

```
import curses
import locale
import time
import random
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()

def sorteia_maca(screen):
    pos = random.randrange(0, curses.COLS), random.randrange(0, curses.LINES)
    screen.addstr(pos[1], pos[0], b"@")

def main(screen):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    screen.nodelay(True)
    y, x = 20, 20
    direction = (1, 0)
    comprimento = 5
    corpo = []
    sorteia_maca(screen)
    pontuacao = 0
    while True:
        key = screen.getch()
        if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            direction = (-1, 0)
        elif key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            direction = (1, 0)
        elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            direction = (0, 1)
        elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
            direction = (0, -1)
        elif key in (0x1b, ord("q")): # <ESC>
            break
        x += direction[0]
        y += direction[1]

        corpo.insert(0, (x, y))
        if len(corpo) > comprimento:
            final = corpo.pop()
            screen.addstr(final[1], final[0], b" ")

        cabeca_em = screen.instr(y, x, 1)
        if cabeca_em == b"@":
            pontuacao += 5
            comprimento += 5
            sorteia_maca(screen)

        elif cabeca_em != b" " or x >= curses.COLS or y > curses.LINES or x < 0 or y < 0:
            screen.addstr(10, 15, "Você morreu! Pontos: {}".format(pontuacao).encode(encoding))
            screen.refresh()
            time.sleep(3)
            break

        screen.addstr(y, x, b"*")
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Pronto - completamente jogável!  Você pode incrementa-lo com várias coisas agora - por exemplo, fazendo a maçã mudar de lugar de tempos em tempos, pode colocar "fases" com "paredes" e aumentando a velocidade, pode mudar para uma tela gráfica usando "pygame" ou outro framework, em vez de mante-lo em modo texto, pode escrever uma classe em orientação a objetos pra cobrinha - permitindo que você tenha mais instâncias dela na mesma tela, as demais sendo controladas pelo computador (ou - ligar o jogo em rede, e ter uma cobrinha controlada por outro jogador)

Answer (score 2):

## Respondendo dúvidas específicas da implementação na pergunta, sobre o jogo da cobrinha

Ok - vou deixar a outra resposta como referência para quem quiser implementar o Jogo da Cobrinha em Python. Aqui, vou comentar sobre o seu problema -que é algo usando "input" que parece com o jogo da cobrinha.

## Movendo a cobra

No exercício proposto, a cobrinha é dada simplesmente por um número inteiro, com tantos dígitos quanto forem o comprimento real da cobra.
Ao obter o dado de uma nova direção, simplesmente multiplique o numero anterior por 10 (acrescentando assim um "0" ao final) e some o número de um dígito representando a direção atual.  Ex.: se a cobrinha atual é representada pela sequÊncia 2232 e se move de novo na direção 3, o número se tornará 22323.  Para limitar o tamanho da cobrinha, você pode pegar o resto da divisão 10 ** N (sendo N o tamanho da cobrinha) por esse número. Nesse exemplo, se a cobrinha tem que ficar com tamanho "4", o resto da divisão de 22323 por 10000 (10 ** 4) é 2323 - o número mais a direita foi descartado. - você não precisa de uma função só pra essa inserção: são duas linhas de código - mas pode faze-lo se quiser.

(Por outro lado, a parte principal do seu programa está no corpo do módulo, fora de qualquer função: isso não só é uma bagunça considerável, como nem sequer vai funcionar - já que as linhas no corpo do módulo são executadas antes das linhas que definem as funções em si, mais abaixo no programa. Essa parte principal do programa *deve* ser colocada numa função - mesmo que seja chamada uma única vez - e na última linha do programa você chama essa função)

(dica 2: no mundo real, Python tem "listas" para guardar esse tipo de dados guardado como um inteiro - e linguagens que não são Python e não tem listas, como C, também não tem inteiros de tamanho arbitrário que possam ser usados pra esse fim, então essa é uma restrinção *bem* artificial do exercício)

## Imprimindo o tabuleiro

Esse aí talvez seja o coração do problema. A questão é que sem uma biblioteca de terminal que permita que você iprima um caratcére em qualquer posição que quiser, você só pode imprimir a tela "de cima pra baixo": isso é - primeiro a linha do topo, depois a linha abaixo dessa, e assim por diante até a última linha. Então, se você deixar pra "descobrir" durante  a impressão que a cobrinha "desceu", e quiser imprimir uma parte do corpo dela uma linha pra cima, não tem como.

São dois caminhos possíveis:

1. Criar uma matriz 2D em memória *antes* de imprimir, com cada posição representando uma posição na tela  - aí vocẽ acompanha as direções da cobrinha, "Desenhando-a" nessa matriz - a vantagem é que você pode desenhar em qualquer ponto.  E no passo seguinte, você imprime essa matriz, começando das linhas de cima - como a cobra inteira está desenhada, não haverão problemas .
2. Você pode ao imprimir cada caractere de cada linha, da esquerda pra direita e de cima pra baixo, chamar uma função como a que você quer que seja a sua `pos_ocupada`: se ela retornar verdadeiro para aquela posição, você imprimei ali um "*" para representar o corpo da cobra, senão imprime um " ".  Essa é a opção mais fácil de programar - SE - a função "pos_ocupada"  já funcionar - mas não parece ser o caso (vamos ver o código dela agora). Por outro lado também é uma solução que se exige que o todas as posições da cobra sejam calculadas múltiplas vezes em cada quadro do jogo.  Esse jogo é assíncrona, e 10 ou 20 posições da cobrinha sao algo insignificante comparadas com as velocidade de um PC onde você roda Python - mas é algo ineficiente por natureza - para cada caractere da tela, vamos dizer que sejam 40 colunas por 20 linhas, você vai calcular a cobrinha inteira.  Numa entrevista de emprego, significa que você é rejeitado no ato. Num trabalho real, significa um trecho do jogo que fica centenas a milhares de vezes mais lento (e consumindo mais bateria) do que da outra forma.  Não é bom encorajar um pensamento do tipo.

O - fui ver o código da sua função "pos_ocupada" - ela está boa - só que, sem nem olhar com muita atenção, dá pra dizer que você nunca rodou a função -e não sabe mesmo se ela funciona.  POr que tem dois erros: a variável "achei" está grafada uma hora como `Achei` outra como `achei` - e você nunca usa o resultado dessa variável, simplesmente retorna "True" sempre. E na verdade, você nem precisa dessa variável - se em qualquer momento a condição `x == x0 and y == y0`, a cobrinha ocupa a posição "x, y", e você pode retornar True. Se chegar ao final do while, pode retornas `False`. Então é só mudar o final dessa função para:

```
   if x == x0 and y == y0:
        return True

return False
```

(Aproveite e leia sobe os "enhance assignment operators" e veja como você deveria estar escrevendo `x0 += 1` em vez de `x0 == x0 + 1`). Quanto aos `if` na sua função - você não fala no seu enunciado, e como não chega a imprimri nada não dá para saber - mas em computação, via de regra, a ordenada "y" começa em 0 "em cima" e aumenta para baixo - princialete n oo modo texto, falamos de "linha 1, linha 2, linha 3", uma embaixo da outra. Como esse sistema louco que seu professor inventou vai achando as posições anteriores do corpo da cobrinha analizando a direção "de onde ela veio" (isso é, quando a cobrinha vai pra esquerda: direção "1", significa que a parte depois da cabeça está a "direita" da cabeça.  A função "pos_ocupada" então avança pra "direita" ao encontrar o código de direção pra "esquerda" que o usuário tiver entrado). Ok - não sei se essa parte do código é sua ou do foi passada como dica pelo professor - mas tenha certeza de entender essa parte anterior, entre parênteses, antes de continuar.

De qualquer forma, para um sistema de coordenadas em que o y cresça para baixo, os "if" relativos ao  "y0" estão invertidos. Se a cobra veio para baixo (direção 4) a parte anterior do corpo dela está na linha de cima, então é preciso subtrair 1 de y0 - o código está somando em vez de subtrair.

Bom, com o "pos_ocupada" arrumado, fica bem simples usar o método (1) acima: um `for y` percorrendo todas as linhas, dentro dele um `for x` percorrento todas as colunas - e aí, você imprime um caractere "*" ou " " dependendo de `posocupada(...,x ,y)` retornar verdadeiro ou falso. (EM Python3, a função print permite imprimir um único caractere, sem mudar de linha se você passar o parâmetro com nome `end` com o valor de uma string vazia: `print(caractere, end="")` (e ao final do "for x", antes de iniciar uma nova interalçao do  "for y", use um print vazio para mudar de linha. 
(ufa - escrever esse parágrafo foi muito mais cansativo do que escrever o código direto, mas tenho que deixar algo pra você fazer).

Possivelmente esse método (1) é o que o seu professor tinha em mente ao propor o exercício.  PRINCIPALMENTE se ele deu a dica de escrever essa função "pos_ocupada".  Mas, se fosse um exercício meu, eu não daria nota máxima, e se em vez de prova, fosse uma entrevista de emprego....

Para o método (2): A primeira coisa é criar uma matriz bidimensional - chega a ser engraçado, mas Python não tem algo desse tipo pronto. COm as funcionalidades de "operator overloading" seria realmente bem fácil criar um objeto especializado que acita um par de elementos como índice, que poderia funcionar como coordenadas.  Mas não é o seu exercício. Um outro jeito, é usar um dicionário - Python permit que uma tupla "x,y" seja uma chave de dicionário - então se uma função com o código muito parecido com  "pos_ocupada" criar um elemento num dicionário vazio em todas as posições "x0"  e "y0" que estão ocupadas, você pode ler esse dicionário no momento da impressão -  e o corpo da cobra vai ser calculado uma única vez. Nesse caso, o dicionário estaria funcionando como uma "matriz esparsa" - é bom código - simples, eficiente - mas você *tem* que aprender em algum momento a criar uma matriz 2D em Python, que é fazendo uma "lista de listas" e fazer uso dela, e  juntar seus elementos para criar a impressão com um único `print`. (VOltando à prova e entrevista de emprego: eu seria mais impressionado, NESSE caso pelo código usando dicionário - mas não se a pessoa tivesse usado uma receita pronta e não soubesse manipular uma lista de listas como uma matriz 2D.

Código para criar a matriz:

```
tela = []
for y in range(linhas):
   tela.append([" "] * colunas)
```

Pronto, agora você pode usr posições do tipo
tela[y0][x0] para guardar um valor numa única posição do seu jogo - 
seja um "*" para o corpo da cobrinha, ou outros caractéres se o jogo
viesse a ter "maçãs" ou "paredes".

Voce pode criar uma tela em branco no começo da função "pos_ocupada" (ou uma função com o mesmo algoritmo, mas outro nome), marcar cada posição da cobrinha, fazendo, dentro do while  `tela[x0][y0] = "*"`e devolver a tela "preenchida".

PAra imprimir essa estrutura, usamos o método `join` das strings. `join` acita uma sequência como parâmetro, e cria uma ´unica string em que os elementos da sequência são colados juntos, separados pela string original do `join` (que é um método) - se a string for um caractere de quebra de linha ("\n"), o resultado é uma string que pode ser impressa, e imprimirá cada elemento da lista "joinada" em uma linha diferente. Se for uma string vazia, todas as strings da lista são simplesmente coladas em sequência.

Então, é possível fazer `print ('\n'.join(''.join(linha) for linha in tela))` para imprimir essa "tela" toda de uma vez.

(Pronto, agora você tem como prosseguir com o exercício)

Comment: Faça um *edit* na resposta acima, **Problema e Explicação**, e anexe essa resposta.

Comment: Sério ? A plataforma _Recomenda_ 1 resposta por pergunta. Mas são duas coisas completametne diferentes, eo texto ficaria muito grande.  

Se algéum for buscar "jogo da cobrinha em Python" - a resposta acima é a boa. Pra respodner a pergutna do OP, essa é melhor - não vej por que não manter separado - se fosse proibido ter duas respostas do mesmo autor, a plataforma simplesmente não permitiria.

Comment: (Só para esclarecer, o "Serio?" que começa o comentário acima não era pra ser de afronta - era pra perguntar se o @Edilson realmente queria que eu fizesse isso.  Só que na hora de ler ficou parecendo uma afronta mal educada - desculpem. Revisitando as respostas agora, parece que faz realmente sentido manter as duas respostas)